# Не работает синтаксис SASS в Sublime Text 3

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, sass

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: установил плагин SASS в package в ST3. После этого в настройках синтаксиса включил тип SASS и в файле с расширением .sass начал писать код. Но проблема в том, что синтаксис не подсвечивается, и переменные не выделяются. При попытке скомпилировать .sass в .css с помощью Koala, выбрасывается ошибка, которая указывает на неверный синтаксис. Также после написания класс элемента, после нажатия Enter, на следующей строке автоматический таб не срабатывает. Несколько раз переустанавливал сам плагин, перезапускал SB3, ничего не помгло, надеюсь на вашу помощь)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Почему в объявлении переменной на второй строке `$color`, а не `$color2`?

```
$color: #000;
$color2 #333;
```

Comment: Боюсь это и есть ответ на вопрос

Comment: Сори, не заметил исправления. Увидел вопросительную интонацию

Comment: Да, недоглядел переменную color2. Изменял код несколько раз, не заметил, вот и двойку не поставил, но сути это не меняет. Ситуация прежняя(

Answer (score 0):

В sass почему после значения ставишь
";".
SASS имеет свободный синтаксис, в котором нет точек с запятой и много пробелов

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]